# Lightning Record Page: Only for overriding default record page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, navigation, app-builder

I started playing around with Lightning Builder creating App pages that I am able to activate and navigate to from a lightning component.

I thought it would be cool to create a "Record Page" lightning page and throw some custom components on it.  For example, I created a record page for Contact.  Now, I only want that record page "version" to be used specifically when I navigate to it from one of my components.  The problem I see with this is that Activation of this page doesn't allow for such a thing.  Activation has to be done on org, app, profile, and/or record types.

There is no way, that I see, to activate a custom record page and only have that version render when my component that controls navigation says so.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. There's no way to specify which App Builder Page is shown when you navigate to a record programmatically. You might want to submit an idea on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) if you're interested in having this feature.